# Logic For Exporting a Grid in Excel

Tags: c#, gridview, export-to-excel

I am trying to export an excel file of a Grid which follows Custom Aggregating. Like It combines all the common Row Values as One. I somehow managed to do that but now I am getting trouble in exporting the GridView Table as excel file because the rows at some places get merged with one another and that causes the excel file being different from from the original gridview.
The Gridview is something like
[image]

But the Printed Excel is something Like [image]

Here You can see the Irregularities in the row of Capital Goods and Construction.

The Code For the Same is

```
private void ExportDataTableToExcel(DataTable dt)
        {
            try
            {
                using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
                {
                    IXLWorksheet sheet = wb.Worksheets.Add(ddlDistrict.SelectedValue);

                    IXLCell cel = sheet.Cell(1, 1);
                    cel.SetValue("S.No");

                    cel = sheet.Cell(1, 2);
                    cel.SetValue("Sector");

                    cel = sheet.Cell(1, 3);
                    cel.SetValue("HR Demand 2019-2023");

                    cel = sheet.Cell(1, 4);
                    cel.SetValue("Expected Demand 2020-2021");

                    cel = sheet.Cell(1, 5);
                    cel.SetValue("% Distribution of Sectors");

                    cel = sheet.Cell(1, 6);
                    cel.SetValue("Target as % Distribution");

                    cel = sheet.Cell(1, 7);
                    cel.SetValue("Actual Target Considered");

                    cel = sheet.Cell(1, 8);
                    cel.SetValue("Unmatched Job Role");

                    cel = sheet.Cell(1, 9);
                    cel.SetValue("Job Role");

                    cel = sheet.Cell(1, 10);
                    cel.SetValue("Job Role Duration");
                    cel = sheet.Cell(1, 11);
                    cel.SetValue("Training Target");

                    for (int r = 2; r <= dt.Rows.Count + 1; r++)
                    {
                        cel = sheet.Cell(r, 1);
                        cel.SetValue(dt.Rows[r - 2]["SerialNo"].ToString());

                        cel = sheet.Cell(r, 2);
                        cel.SetValue(dt.Rows[r - 2]["Sector"].ToString());

                        cel = sheet.Cell(r, 3);
                        cel.SetValue(dt.Rows[r - 2]["HRDemand_2019_2023"].ToString());

                        cel = sheet.Cell(r, 4);
                        cel.SetValue(dt.Rows[r - 2]["ExpectedDemand"].ToString());

                        cel = sheet.Cell(r, 5);
                        cel.SetValue(dt.Rows[r - 2]["PrcntDistSector"].ToString());

                        cel = sheet.Cell(r, 6);
                        cel.SetValue(dt.Rows[r - 2]["TargetOnPrcntDistSector"].ToString());

                        cel = sheet.Cell(r, 7);
                        cel.SetValue(dt.Rows[r - 2]["ActualConsiderTarget"].ToString());

                        cel = sheet.Cell(r, 8);
                        cel.SetValue(dt.Rows[r - 2]["UnmatchedJobRole"].ToString());

                        cel = sheet.Cell(r, 9);
                        cel.SetValue(dt.Rows[r - 2]["JobRole"].ToString());

                        cel = sheet.Cell(r, 10);
                        cel.SetValue(dt.Rows[r - 2]["JobroleDurInHrs"].ToString());

                        cel = sheet.Cell(r, 11);
                        cel.SetValue(dt.Rows[r - 2]["TrainingTarget"].ToString());
                    }

                    int Ri = sheet.Rows().Count(), Cj = sheet.Columns().Count();
                    for (int j = 1; j <= 11; j++)
                    {
                        int rowI = 0, rowC = 0;
                        for (int i = 1; i <= Ri; i++)
                        {
                            string rowText = sheet.Cell(i, j).Value.ToString();
                            string nextRowText = sheet.Cell(i + 1, j).Value.ToString();
                            if (rowText == nextRowText)
                            {
                                rowC += 1;
                                if (rowI == 0) rowI = i;
                                continue;
                            }
                            if (rowC > 1)
                            {
                                IXLAddress addressI = sheet.Cell(rowI, j).Address;
                                IXLAddress addressCI = sheet.Cell(rowI > 1 ? rowC + rowI : rowI, j).Address;
                                sheet.Range(addressI.ToString() + ":" + addressCI.ToString()).Merge();
                                rowI = 0; rowC = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    IXLRange range = sheet.Range(sheet.Cell(1, 1).Address, sheet.Cell(1, sheet.Columns().Count()).Address);
                    range.Style.Fill.SetBackgroundColor(XLColor.FromHtml("#195e83"));
                    range.Style.Font.SetFontColor(XLColor.White);
                    range.Style.Alignment.SetHorizontal(XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center);
                    range.Style.Alignment.SetVertical(XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Center);
                    sheet.Columns().AdjustToContents();
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=DSDP_REPORT.xlsx");
                    using (MemoryStream MyMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        wb.SaveAs(MyMemoryStream);
                        MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                        Response.Flush();
                        Response.End();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
```

The Code For the GridView is

```
protected void gvDemandEmpSectors_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] colLableControl = { "gv_lblSector" };
            int RowSpan = 2;

            for (int i = gvDemandEmpSectors.Rows.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                GridViewRow row = gvDemandEmpSectors.Rows[i];
                GridViewRow previousRow = gvDemandEmpSectors.Rows[i - 1];

                string rowText = (row.Cells[1].FindControl("gv_lblSector") as Label).Text;

                string previousRowText = (previousRow.Cells[1].FindControl("gv_lblSector") as Label).Text;
                if (rowText.ToString() == previousRowText.ToString())
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
                    {
                        previousRow.Cells[j].RowSpan = RowSpan;
                        row.Cells[j].Visible = false;
                    }

                    RowSpan += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    RowSpan = 2;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I need help to figure out the error so that I can go forward with my project.